# Only the first of three custom views draws properly

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a custom ScoreView that consists of two lines of text (a name and a score). Behind that text, I am drawing a bar representing the score.

I have a fragment that contains three such ScoreViews. When I update the ScoreViews with a new name or score, everything works fine. However, if I update the rectangle behind them, only the first rectangle is redrawn.

The end result is something like this:

[image]

All three ScoreViews should have a gray bar behind the text.

To prevent the possibility of my fill color attribute causing this, I am statically setting the bar's color in the ScoreView.

**ScoreView snippet:**

```java
public class ScoreView extends View {

    public void setFillPercent(float percent) {
        mFillPercent = percent;
        mFillRect = new Rect(getLeft(), getTop(), getLeft() + Math.round(mFillPercent*getWidth()), getBottom());
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mFillRect = new Rect(getLeft(), getTop(), getLeft() + Math.round(mFillPercent*w), getBottom());
        mTextXPos = getLeft() + 20; // TODO dp?
        mNameTextYPos = h/2 - (int)mNameTextSize;
        mScoreTextYPos = h/2 + (int)mScoreTextSize;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(mFillRect, mFillPaint);
        canvas.drawText(mName, mTextXPos, mNameTextYPos, mNameTextPaint);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(mScore), mTextXPos, mScoreTextYPos, mScoreTextPaint);
    }
}
```

In my fragment, I call:

```java
oneScoreView.setFillPercent(.5f);
twoScoreView.setFillPercent(.5f);
threeScoreView.setFillPercent(.5f);
```

I set a breakpoint in `onDraw()` and I can see that it is being called, and that `mFillRect` has the correct size and position. It simply doesn't get displayed.

I also discovered that if I rearrange the three ScoreViews, it is always the first ScoreView that updates properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but `mFillRect = new Rect(getLeft(), getTop(), getLeft()` it means you set offset left and top of the view, but then you use this rectangle to draw inside the same view. I think it's just out of view's canvas area, that's why you cannot see it. I might be wrong though.

Comment: I've checked my math a few times, and I'm pretty sure everything should fit in the View. I'm setting the right bound (third parameter) to the left edge of the View plus some number of pixels. Top and bottom simply match the View's top and bottom bounds.

Comment: Well, that's true and right. But when you draw, you draw offset of the view inside the view. Simply saying example: view (left = 100, with = 10). When onDraw happens I draw rect with x = 100 and with 10. But the view has width = 10 and rect's offset 100, it will be out of the view on 90 (100 - 10), so it will not be drawn because of the bounds. Hope I've explained good enough.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. And indeed, switching to `new Rect(0, 0, fillWidth, getHeight())` works like a charm!